# Overlay 'master' view for splitviewcontroller on ipadOS

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, ipados

I want to reproduce the 'master' view from the 'Find my' app in ipadOS. It looks like a splitviewcontroller but the 'master' view is like an overlay and this is very convenient if you have a map behind. I can't find the docs surrounding this. Any idea how to do this?

[image: example of Find my app on ipadOS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in system API to achieve this floating overlay effect, but people have tried to recreate it and made their efforts open-source.

This is not as easy as using a UISplitViewController, you will instead need to define your own presentation viewcontroller and presentation animations.

This makes things a lot more difficult, as you will also have to think about

- Device orientation changes
- Behavior on iPadOS vs iOS
- Having multiple instances of your app open at once (on iPadOS)
- How should tableviews behave on scrolling?

I am aware of the following open-source projects on GitHub that partially solve your problem. Let me give you a quick overview:

- [Pulley](https://github.com/52inc/Pulley): Replicates the visual effect for iPad that you aim for, but iirc lacks some intuitive behavior when it come to scrollviews or tableviews.
- [OverlayContainer](https://github.com/applidium/OverlayContainer): Only creates the iOS version of the "overlay effect" but does that extraordinarily well while also giving you more fine-grained control.
- [FloatingPanel](https://github.com/SCENEE/FloatingPanel), which I do not have any experience with

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer i was looking for, Pulley seems like a very nice copy.